# My ion-content is overlapping with the header in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 App and I have installed the Ionic 4 tab theme and I have made the header common by adding the header code in the **app.component.html** but the problem is that my  is overlapping with the header.

This is my **app.component.html**:

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-icon name="more" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-app>
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

This is my **tab1.page.html**:

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
        <ion-img src="/assets/shapes.svg"></ion-img>
        <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>Get Started</ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>Welcome to Ionic</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
        <p>Now that your app has been created, you'll want to start building out features and components. Check out some of the resources below for next steps.</p>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I have just installed the fresh theme of tabs in Ionic 4 and I have done these changes only.

[image]

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

This is my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3pqhwc?file=app%2Fapp.html)

Comment: Setting a common header is what ionic team does not want you to do, a header is intended to be on each page. You can make your life a little easier and make a custom header component, which you will just then add on the top of your pages like: `<my-custom-header></my-custom-header>`

Comment: @AJT_82. I have added the my stackblitz. Can you please add the component to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the overlapping of `ion-content` you should add a style to the `ion-content`

```
<ion-content class="content"></ion-content>

.content{
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

You can try the above way or else try if this works..

```
<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

Add padding to the `ion-content` tag

You can check any other solution suits for you here [ion-content overlaps with header](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-content-overlaps-in-ion-header/109913)

Comment: When I add the class to the ion-content and give the margin, it is not taking the margin.

Comment: So, It is okay to define the header code in app.component.html for making it common.

Comment: add padding to the `ion-content` and check if it works

Comment: if you need the header for all the pages then its better to put them in the app.component.html otherwise if you need for specific pages you can put them in your page

Comment: I have added in the app.component.html only and I have added the image of DOM. Can you please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189116/discussion-between-sivaramakrishnan-and-raghav).

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Can you please check my StackBlitz?

Comment: did you find any solution @Raghav ? I am facing this same issue and I don't want to rely on padding or margin.

Comment: Hi @Divya. I think this can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Could you try this;

```
<ion-app>
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-icon name="more" slot="end"></ion-icon>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't want to deal with approximative css styles, [@AJT82](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902046/my-ion-content-is-overlapping-with-the-header-in-ionic-4#comment96592267_54902046) pointed out the right way to deal with this. By creating a custom header component, you won't have to use any margin or padding styles. Also, you will have the choice to display a custom title on specific page.

Assuming my toolbar needs to be on my component `HomePageModule`, I created a subcomponent `toolbar.ts`. Then I import it inside `home.module.ts` and declare it into `home.page.html`.

**toolbar.ts**
using `Input` to retrieve the `title` parameter from html:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: 'toolbar.html',
  styleUrls: ['toolbar.scss']
})
export class AppToolbar {
  @Input() public title: string;

  constructor() {}
}
```

**toolbar.html**
display the `title` receive from the module:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

**home.module.ts**
import the `toolbar`'s module:

```
import { AppToolbar } from './toolbar/toolbar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppToolbar]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

**home.page.html**
then, declare it inside the `home` template with the `title` parameter:

```
<app-toolbar [title]="'My Custom Title'"></app-toolbar>

<ion-content>
    <!-- content -->
</ion-content>
```

Each page should import this component and declare it into its html page. By using this, the `toolbar` doesn't overloap the content page, and it can display a specific title.